Inheritance of C# functions and using reusability
I'm drawing a complete blank on what to call what I want to do (hence the difficulty I am having in trying to research it). But what I do have is this:
public interface IShapes
{
    public void Draw();
}
public class Square : IShapes
{
    public void Draw()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetType().FullName?.Substring(GetType().FullName.IndexOf('.') + 1) + " - Draw");
    }
}
public class Circle : IShapes
{
    public void Draw()
    {
    Console.WriteLine(GetType().FullName?.Substring(GetType().FullName.IndexOf('.')+1) + " - Draw");
    }
}

I want to get rid of the code duplication, changing the interface into something appropriate like maybe a class, but then using reflection to call the correct (i.e., the 'most' child inheritance) Draw method.
So elsewhere I could have a call like (to follow the code sample above):
var shapes = new List<IShapes>();
shapes.Add(new Circle());
shapes.Add(new Square());

shapes.ForEach((s) => 
{
s.Draw();
});

This would result in a 'Circle - Draw' and a 'Square - Draw'
I have tried changing the interface into a class (and an abstract) but I feel like I am missing something obvious.
I have also tried, in the Square and Circle : Shapes classes to define public new void Draw() methods that call base.Draw() directly but that doesn't seem to work either.

if you have some common functionality, create an (abstract) base-class. So, yes, some Shape-class would be feasible. No need for reflection, though. Polymorphism is about using the most specific override of a function.

First of all, you would greatly simplify your methods by just using nameof to get the class name.

@JonasH you cannot use nameof here - or rather, it does something different; the existing code fetches the concrete type's name, which nameof cannot know; since Square and Circle are not sealed, it might not be them

You may want to consider the visitor pattern. Since this can allow you to implement drawing methods for each kind of shape, without the shapes needing to depend on any particular drawing library.

Depending on your target framework, "default interface methods" might be your friend:
using System;
public interface IShapes
{
    public void Draw()
    {
    
    Console.WriteLine(GetType().FullName?.Substring(GetType().FullName.IndexOf('.') + 1) + " - Draw");
    }
}
public class Square : IShapes {}
public class Circle : IShapes {}


I was about to answer this when I got 2 spam calls, one local and one from some 60K people city in .... Holland!

@PanagiotisKanavos I told them not to use my name during the distraction operation... plausible deniability etc

Thank you this seemed to work for me. I actually thought you couldn't provide base logic code for interfaces (although I guess this is what you meant by 'target framework') as the whole point, I thought, was to basically write a 'skeleton' for a list of common components something had to implement to be an 'IShape'.

@john yep, this only works in ... I haven't checked but I want to say net6 and above?

(Note: This answer assumes that you want to actually have different implementations of Draw() for the derived classes. If you do not need to do that then you can use one of the other answers to your question!)
You can introduce an intermediary abstract base class which implements the functionality:
public interface IShapes
{
    public void Draw();
}

public abstract class ShapesBase : IShapes
{
    public virtual void Draw()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetType().FullName?.Substring(GetType().FullName.IndexOf('.') + 1) + " - Draw");
    }
}

public class Square : ShapesBase
{
    public override void Draw()
    {
        base.Draw();
    }
}

public class Circle : ShapesBase
{
    public override void Draw()
    {
        base.Draw();
    }
}

Note that if you override the Draw() method you MUST remember to still call the base method otherwise you won't get the desired output (I assume that your concrete classes will generally want to implement Draw().
If you omit the Draw() implementations from the concrete classes altogether it will still work:
public interface IShapes
{
    public void Draw();
}

public abstract class ShapesBase : IShapes
{
    public virtual void Draw()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetType().FullName?.Substring(GetType().FullName.IndexOf('.') + 1) + " - Draw");
    }
}

public class Square : ShapesBase
{
}

public class Circle : ShapesBase
{
}

But generally you would be overriding the virtual methods.

Incidentally, if you want to force the derived classes to implement some kind of Draw() method you can take a different approach. You can introduce an abstract DrawImpl() method which the derived classes must implement, and which is called from the abstract base class's concrete implementation of Draw().
This approach does also have the advantage that the derived classes don't need remember to call the base class version:
public interface IShapes
{
    public void Draw();
}

public abstract class ShapesBase : IShapes
{
    protected abstract void DrawCore();

    public void Draw()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetType().FullName?.Substring(GetType().FullName.IndexOf('.') + 1) + " - Draw");
        DrawCore();
    }
}

public class Square : ShapesBase
{
    protected override void DrawCore()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Square.DrawCore()");
    }
}

public class Circle : ShapesBase
{
    protected override void DrawCore()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Circle.DrawCore()");
    }
}


This approach also works if you want to make overriding the DrawCore() method optional, but still get the desired output, simply by declaring DrawCore() as virtual instead of abstract:
public interface IShapes
{
    public void Draw();
}

public abstract class ShapesBase : IShapes
{
    protected virtual void DrawCore()
    {
        // Do nothing.
    }

    public void Draw()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetType().FullName?.Substring(GetType().FullName.IndexOf('.') + 1) + " - Draw");
        DrawCore();
    }
}

public class Square : ShapesBase
{
}

public class Circle : ShapesBase
{
}

This could be useful if only some of the derived classes need to override DrawCore().

Use a generic extension method. This also allows you to use typeof<T> instead of this.GetType() which resolves at compile-time. Also, I'm pretty sure you can just use Name (instead of parsing FullName) which provides the unqualified name.
static class ShapeExtensions
{
    static void Draw<T>(this T shape) where T : IShapes
    {
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(T).Name + " - Draw");
    }
}

Note that typeof(T) will only give you the type of the variable (which is determined at compile time), not the instance (which is determined at runtime). So if you have a List<IShapes> it will always print IShapes - Draw. If you want the runtime type of the instance you can still use GetType().
static void Draw<T>(this T shape) where T : IShapes
{
    Console.WriteLine(shape.GetType().Name + " - Draw");
}

You call it exactly the same way.
shapes.ForEach((s) => 
{
    s.Draw();
});


This didn't seem to work for me as I intended at least, when I called the s.Draw method I just got IShapes - Draw (the rest of the code was the same as above that I put in my original post) for both Circle and Square.

If you want the runtime type you have to use GetType(). I've updated the answer.
